# Get command used to start a script

Tags: shell, get, command

How to get the command previously used to start a shell script?

for example:

```
nohup /script_name.sh &
```

Inside the script itself, how to check if "nohup" has been used?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in a bit detail?

Comment: do you want to check if "nohup" word is present in your script or not?

Comment: I would like to know what command has been issued to start the script. It should be a global variable that store it. I'm obfuscating a custom script, I need that to exit the script under some conditions. Another example is to check if someone is using strace command. That may help other people too.

Comment: is your script(script1) executing another script(script2)? and you want to know what command has been issued in script1 to execute script2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the $_ parameter in your script.

Example: shell.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $_;

user@server [~]# sh shell.sh
/usr/bin/sh
user@server [~]#
```

Additionally:

If you want to get rid of that full path - /usr/bin/sh - utilize basename command.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `basename $_`;

user@server [~]# sh shell.sh
sh
user@server [~]#
```

Answer (score 1):

well that depends on the script in question.There're many ways to execute a script like:

```
 ./<scriptname> #chmod 700 <scriptname> should be done before executing this script
 bash <scriptname> # provided bash is used for executing the script.
```

or if you just want to get the name of script2 in script1, then use sed or awk for parsing the script1 with regular expression => /script2/.

Try this:

```
cat <script1> | awk '{ if( $0 ~ /^[^#].* \/scriptname.sh/ ){ print $1}}'
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, it was not how to start the script, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@codebaus thanks, doing something like this works but using strace definitely not.

```
#!/bin/bash
# echo $_
# echo $0

if grep "sh" $_ >/dev/null ; then
exit 1
fi ;
echo "string" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to run this?:

```
#!/bin/bash
# echo $_
# echo $0

if grep "sh" $_ 2> /dev/null ; then
exit 1
fi ;
echo "string";

user@server [~]# sh shell.sh
Binary file /usr/bin/sh matches
user@server [~]#
```

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish in the end game. But $_ should give you what you need based on your initial question.

Additionally:

As I did not answer your strace comment, apologies. Based on the previous code above.

```
strace sh shell.sh

wait4(-1, Binary file /usr/bin/strace matches
[{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 874
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
```

Comment: I expected that if interpreter is not declared at the script begining, strace can not start the script.

Comment: Right, so you will not get any information from that bash parameter. It is failing. The shell script was never started.

Comment: If you have one script invoking another, it should work fine though.